# C++ Random Double Value

Tags: c++

How do you create a random double between .1 and 2.5?

This is what I have been trying.

```
srand(time(NULL));

((double) rand() / RAND_MAX) * 2.5 + .1
```

Comment: Multiply by the `2.4`, the size of the range (`2.5 - .1`) instead of `2.5`.

Comment: @Paulpro You should post that as an answer.

Comment: `std::uniform_real_distribution` .

Answer (score 4):

The modern way is to use a random number distribution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    random_device rd;
    mt19937_64 generator(rd());
    uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution(0.1, 2.5);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        double d = distribution(generator);
        cout << d << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `0.1 <= d < 2.5`.

Comment: Yeah, use `std::rand` is really a bad practice.

Comment: I can't go that far. It depends too much on what you need that random number for. If you need quick and don't mind dirty, don't use a more expensive option.

Comment: Two suggestions - 1) use `random_device` for the seed. 2) instead of `default_random_engine` which you don't know what will be (and could be as bad as `rand`), use `mt19937`.

Comment: A warning about `random_device`: The C++ Standard  allows it to be implemented a little too simplistically. Make sure that your tool chain's library implementation is actually generating random sequences with a couple tests.

Comment: Seeding with a single call to `std::random_device` is actually pretty bad, but there isn't a quick and easy solution. In some cases, `std::random_device` is another prng with fixed seed